# Termination of contract during notice period

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, termination, legal

I am on my notice period and I have a workplace injury that has not allowed me to go into work. I’m in the UK and now my employer wants to terminate the contract because I’m going to my home country to get treatment for the same temporarily saying that it will put them in a difficult position while filing taxes. I’m not sure how this works. This is leaving me with 2 weeks of no pay I think and which is a lot since I am a part time employee. Is this even legal to do?

Comment: What does your contract say how long the notice period is if they terminate the contract?

Comment: I am in the midst of my notice period with 3 weeks left.

Comment: Places like Citizens Advice will be able to help you or point you to relevant help.

Comment: @nvoigt unless the employer is invoking a "gross misconduct" clause, the employer's notice cannot be less than the employee's notice in the UK. A lot here will depend on whether the poster has been formally signed off work by a GP.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. The reason I have to fly is because the NHS hasn’t still given me an appointment to further investigate the injury. Not sure how that plays out here.

Comment: @AadiChabukswar did you doctor (here, in the uk, who examined you) clear you for work or not?

Comment: My work involves a lot of heavy lifting so no I was advised not to bend stand excessively or lift heavy things but unfortunately due to over the phone consultation I don’t have anything in written

Comment: @AadiChabukswar i mean, if it's not bad enough that you are not at the A&E waiting to be seen, it's likely not bad enough you cannot show up for work. So why are you not at the a&e? Like I don't want to be mean, but I can see why the employer would be annoyed in that situation.

Comment: @AidaPaul what should he do when he shows up for work but has been told not to lift heavy things and his work is lifting heavy things?

Comment: @mattfreake there's a process for this for a reason. If this isn't serious enough to get a doc appointment (or wait better part of a day at a&e), it's likely not serious enough to stop you from doing your work. Pretty simple. You do either, you get diagnosed, get a doctors note and take it from there.

Comment: Why would you seek treatment overseas for a diagnosis given over the phone?

Comment: @AidaPaul, that's silly talk. It's completely normal to be physically injured/healing so that one cannot do heavy lifting or stand around all day, without it being a medical emergency or require any solution but physical rest. I don't know what country you're in but the NHS is collapsing due to underfunding - people are waiting hours in A&E with heart attacks, and you're lucky if you get a face-to-face doctor's appointment in six weeks (*if* the doctor thinks it's necessary).

Comment: @Kilisi, because the NHS is falling apart due to underfunding, and even relatively tin-pot countries now have better and more accessible public healthcare than the UK. They say it's easier to get a dentist in Ukraine (a country at war) than the UK, and easier to get a doctor in Eastern Europe.

Answer (score 7):

The "difficult position while filing taxes" silliness doesn't pass the sniff test to me - while I don't know enough about your situation regarding residence/right to work status to know whether leaving the country would be an issue in that regard the whole question is rendered moot by you being in you notice period; they could pay you the remaining weeks in lieu of notice and both parties walk away with no further involvement. So I suspect that's simply a lame attempt to not look like they're being callous.

This is going to come down to how much notice they are required to give you in the event of a termination. If you've been there less than two years but more than a month the statutory minimum is one week (and it increases if you've been there [longer](https://www.acas.org.uk/notice-periods/notice-when-being-dismissed-or-made-redundant)) - although your employment contract may well specify a longer period and if so that takes precedence, and since they can't contractually give themselves a shorter notice period then you it's going to matter whether you gave the *minimum* notice period when you resigned or a longer one.

If the minimum notice in the contract is e.g. one week but you voluntarily gave more then they can still terminate you during it - as long as they give you the higher of either contractual or statutory notice periods.

If they're trying to get away with giving you less than the minimum notice and they're doing it *without* reasons amounting to gross misconduct then they aren't allowed to do that.

I **strongly** advise you to contact [acas](https://www.acas.org.uk/contact), it's free and they'll be able to best advise you on how to proceed in your precise circumstances. Ideally do this before you engage further with your employer on the matter.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response ! Yes I’ve been there 9 months now and my notice period was 2 months and now I have 3 weeks of it left

Comment: Income and employment taxes can get very confusing with employees in different countries, especially if the company does not have an office in OPs home country.  This is one reason many companies don't want individual remote workers in a country they don't have a presence in.

Comment: @cdkMoose You're correct - but there's nothing here suggesting that the OP was going to be *working* from the other country, just visiting to seek medical treatment. Obviously if I'm wrong in that then it does potentially bring taxes into play, but even then the employer can (in the overwhelming majority of cases) just deduct UK tax as normal and it's up to the employee to seek relief from HMRC if they've been double taxed. Basically the employer can't go wrong by just treating them as normal when it comes to tax.

Comment: @motosubatsu, if he is still in his notice period, he could still be getting paid for his days, even if he doesn't actually work.  What matters for most of these scenarios is getting paid by employer while you are in country and not on vacation

Comment: Some country's, like the US, have separate obligations for the employer and the employee.  OP going to that country could put the company on the hook for employer's payments, possibly without them even knowing

Comment: @cdkMoose Sorry, I'm still not buying it for this scenario. Three weeks, while on leave (even if it's sick rather than holiday) isn't raising any tax implications for the employer, the only scenario I can think of would be where the OP didn't return and spend the requisite number of days to maintain UK tax residency into FY24-25 which could cause them to have over-taxed them for a couple of weeks - but that would then be the employee's responsibility to claim back from HMRC. But as I mentioned in the answer, even *that* would be completely sidestepped by paying out in lieu of notice instead.